# Using Oracle Java 7 without the plug-in

Tags: java, web-browser, plugins

I need Oracle Java 7 for software running on my Mac, but do not wish to have the plug-in available in my web browsers.

How can I accomplish this configuration and maintain it across Java upgrades?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say just install java as normal. Afterwards go to

System Preferences → Java (bottom row) → Security

and uncheck "Enable Java content in the web browser".

That should do it, and I would very much expect it to remember the setting after an update.